# Why magnet do not feel force?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits

The magnet is falling downward under the action of gravity. As there is relative motion between electrons and magnet the electrons will feel force ( F= qvB )and according to the Newton's third law will apply equal and opposite force to the magnet but in reality it is  seen that no force is applied to the magnet  . Why?[image]

Comment: Your diagram needs some clarification. Is the magnet falling through a thin split ring, or is something else happening here? Also, Newton's third law is misapplied. The magnet and the electrons don't exert equal and opposite forces directly on each other; rather, they exert forces on (i.e. exchange momentum with) the electromagnetic field, which itself is a separate dynamical object. This may seem inconsequential here, but without this fact, the Lorentz force appears to violate Newton's third law.

Answer (score 2):

Its a while since I touched physics, so let me give this answer with whatever best I remember.
Coming back to your question, well, it does. According to Lenz's law, the loop (assuming its closed, not open like the diagram shown), develops a current due to the motion of the magnet, and the the magnetic field developed due to the induced current, does so that it opposes the magnetic field produced by the magnet. So the magnet will slow down as it approaches the coil but continue to fall, if you do the experiment.

Answer (score 2):

The magnet **does** feel a force, as can be seen in this classic demonstration:

> [Lenz's Law with Copper Pipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7tIi71-AjA)

To see what's happening, think of the tube as a stack of loops.  As the magnet moves towards one "loop", it induces a current, and by Lenz's Law, this loop of current acts like a magnet of the opposite polarity.  Thus, the current exerts an upward force on the magnet.

Equilibrium is reached when the magnet moves fast enough that the force from the tube exactly counteracts the force of gravity on the magnet;  at that point, it falls at a constant velocity through the pipe, instead of accelerating downwards.

Comment: Actually in copper pipe, the eletron can move in a closed loop . But here loop is not closed

Answer (score 1):

The negative electrons feel a force. So do the positive copper nuclei, and there are as many positive charges as negative ones in the copper. But the electrons are light (and the conduction electrons are not strongly bound) so they can give a current, whereas the copper nuclei are heavy and they stay put. The forces are equal but the accelerations/currents are very different.

Both forces have a corresponding Newton 3 force on the magnet, but as they are equal and opposite they cancel.

Answer (score 1):

As the loop is open only a transient current can run in it. This will cause opposite charges to pile up at its end points.  This *will* cause a  force on the magnet, only not as large as with a closed loop.